# Problem with nested SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, nested

I have a problem with nested select in MySQL.

This one works, but I need to get two of them.

Example:

```
SELECT `a`.`title` , `a`.`askprice` , `a`.`picture` 
, `a`.`description` , `a`.`userid` , `a`.`id`
FROM (
`mm_ads_fields_values` AS afv
)
LEFT JOIN `mm_ads` AS a ON `a`.`id` = `afv`.`aid`
WHERE `afv`.`value` = '38'
AND `a`.`category` = '227'
AND `a`.`status` =1
AND a.id
IN (
    SELECT a.id
    FROM mm_ads AS a
    LEFT JOIN mm_ads_fields_values AS afv ON afv.aid = a.id
    WHERE afv.value = '2913'
)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

This one works. But I need SQL statement like this one:

```
SELECT `a`.`title` , `a`.`askprice` , `a`.`picture` 
, `a`.`description` , `a`.`userid` , `a`.`id`
FROM (
`mm_ads_fields_values` AS afv
)
LEFT JOIN `mm_ads` AS a ON `a`.`id` = `afv`.`aid`
WHERE `afv`.`value` = '38'
AND `a`.`category` = '227'
AND `a`.`status` =1
AND a.id
IN (
   SELECT a.id
   FROM mm_ads AS a
   LEFT JOIN mm_ads_fields_values AS afv ON afv.aid = a.id
   WHERE afv.value = '2913'
)
AND a.id
IN (
    SELECT a.id
    FROM mm_ads AS a
    LEFT JOIN mm_ads_fields_values AS afv ON afv.aid = a.id
    WHERE afv.value = '51'
)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

And this one, last one, won't work. Its loading, loading and never nothing happen..

What am I doing wrong?

Regards, Mario

Sorry for my bad English..

Comment: Could you please edit your original question and post back the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...` output.

Comment: Could you give us a sentence or two explaining the desired outcome or goal for your SQL statements. What are your trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Glib answer: shouldn't the second IN statement use OR instead of AND? (edit: and use correct operator precedence.)

```
...
AND 
( a.id
  IN (
     SELECT a.id
     FROM mm_ads AS a
     LEFT JOIN mm_ads_fields_values AS afv ON afv.aid = a.id
     WHERE afv.value = '2913'
  )
  OR a.id
  IN (
      SELECT a.id
      FROM mm_ads AS a
      LEFT JOIN mm_ads_fields_values AS afv ON afv.aid = a.id
      WHERE afv.value = '51'
  )
)
...
```

Comment: If I try your example, phpmyadmin loading into infinity.. I need that SQL statement for filters in ads page. For example, I am viewing cars, they have filters: Brand, Model, Type,... If I click on BMW, and I select M3, I need to have two nested selects, right? There must be AND instead OR, right?

Comment: Is maybe any other way how to deal with it?

Comment: on your very first query (the one that works) change `WHERE afv.value = '2913'` to `WHERE afv.value = '2913' OR afv.value = '51'`

Comment: This one works but it's not what I need. I want to reduce search results. I want to get only ads that has options 2913 AND 51, in this case.